# Cleaning legacy country records in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I am trying to clean a dataset which includes data for legacy countries. I want to distribute the values for these to successor new country rows based on the proportion that each of those successor countries makes up of the total. Eg. for each variable in 'Successor country X' I want add to the existing value a portion of the 'Old country' value. I have 30 variables in total. After this, I want to remove the 'Old country' rows.

Here is a simplified version of my dataframe (I actually have multiple old countries):

```
Country                   Var1    Var2   Var3 ......Var30
1   Old country           30      18     20       
2   Successor country 1   5       1      1
3   Successor country 2   10      1      0
4   Successor country 3   15      1      3
```

And I'm aiming for....

```
Country                   Var1    Var2   Var3 ......Var30
1   Successor country 1   10      7      6
2   Successor country 2   20      7      0
3   Successor country 3   30      7      18
```

It's the sort of thing I could do quite quickly in Excel but I would really like to learn how to do so in R. I appreciate there may be a few steps required. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have Old country 2, which countries would be its successor countries? I think you need a "family" variable for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidyverse solution:

First some data, the old var denotes old/ successor countries. Class denotes their relationship.

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.table::fread( 
"Country       Var1    Var2   Var3 class  old 
'Old country'           30      18     20  1  1    
'Successor country 1'   5       1      1   1  0
'Successor country 2'   10      1      0   1  0
'Successor country 3'   15      1      3   1  0
'Old country 2'         60      36     40  2  1    
'Successor country 4'   5       1      1   2  0
'Successor country 5'   10      1      0   2  0
'Successor country 6'   15      1      3   2  0
",
header = TRUE,quote = "'")
```

We can write a function to do the splitting.

```r
splitit <- function(var, old){
  # variable for old country
  oldvar = var[which(old == 1)]
  # calculate proportion
  prop <- var
  prop[which(old == 0)] <- var[which(old == 0)]/sum(var[which(old == 0)]) 
  return(prop *oldvar+ var)
}
```

Then we can apply the function `splitit` to all variables starting with "Var", and remove the line for the old country.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Var")),.funs = funs(splitit(., old))) %>% 
  filter (old ==0)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   class [2]
#>   Country              Var1  Var2  Var3 class   old
#>   <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1 Successor country 1    10     7     6     1     0
#> 2 Successor country 2    20     7     0     1     0
#> 3 Successor country 3    30     7    18     1     0
#> 4 Successor country 4    15    13    11     2     0
#> 5 Successor country 5    30    13     0     2     0
#> 6 Successor country 6    45    13    33     2     0
```

---

Edit: code modified to correctly deal with multiple groups.

Comment: Many thanks. This seems like a great solution!
I replaced 'starts_with' with simply a list of the variable names as they are movie genres and don't all start with var. I think this should be 

ok. mutate_at(vars(Action, Adult, Adventure, Animation, Biography, Comedy, Crime, Documentary.... Western)

However I am getting this error:
Column `Action` must be length 15 (the group size) or one, not 154

154 is my total number of records including other countries whereas 15 is the group size. Any ideas?

Comment: hi, @liamt12three I've updated my code in my answer, the `mutate_at()` should be working properly with multiple groups now.